# Sharepoint 2013 advanced Search Contains not behaving like expected

Tags: enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

I have 2 problems with the contains : construction in the search query builder.

I have a document named "thisisatest.docx" in my search index which I can find when doing a search with my search page.

I now have a contentbysearch webpart and I am configuring the query in the query builder to show this document (and other but for testing I am trying to get this one).

My query is:

```
FileName:"this"
```

This has no result. Why? The FileName contains the text "this"

When changing to

```
FileName:"this*"
```

I do get the document why? Because of the *? Is this asterix needed since : means contains?

The other problem I am having is on the ModifiedBy property

My query is

```
ModifiedBy:"FirstName LastName"
```

I get no result

Then I try this with the asterix

```
ModifiedBy:"*FirstName LastName*"
```

Also no result

Then I try this

```
ModifiedBy:*"FirstName LastName"*
```

So the asterix outside the double quotess. I now get the document.

Why is there a difference between these 2 properties and the location of the asterix?

Answer (score 0):

This is common confusion between the "=" and the ":" operator in KQL.

Below is the official description ([link to KQL article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)) of the two operators (notice it does not use "contains" when defining the ":" operator, infact it says equal to)

[image]

with the * operator, what you are refering to is Prefix matching. There are also rules with where and when prefix matching works.

When you specify a phrase for the property value, matched results must contain the specified phrase within the property value that is stored in the full-text index. The following query example returns content items with the text "Advanced Search" in the title, such as "Advanced Search XML", "Learning About the Advanced Search Web Part", and so on:

```
title:"Advanced Search"
```

Prefix matching is also supported with phrases specified in property values, but you must use the wildcard operator (*) in the query, and it is supported only at the end of the phrase, as follows:

```
title:"Advanced Sear*"
```

The following queries do not return the expected results:+

```
title:"Advan* Search"

title:"Advanced Sear"
```

Comment: For filename I can relate it to your answer. But what about the strange behavior with modifiedby? The location of the * seems to go wrong there when its between the " "